# Is there a statistical mechanics proof that internal energy and other thermodynamic potentials are extensive?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics

Assume we want to describe a statistical system. And assume we are working with the constraints of a canoncial ensemble
$$U\overset{!}{=}[H]:=\textrm{tr}(\rho H) \quad \wedge \quad 1\overset{!}{=}\textrm{tr}(\rho)$$
Under these constraints one finds by minimizing the Von-Neumann entropy of the system
$$S=-k\cdot\textrm{tr}(\rho\log\rho)$$
that the density operator is given as
$$\rho=\frac{1}{Z}\exp(-\beta E) \quad \textrm{with} \quad Z=\textrm{tr}(\exp(-\beta H))$$
From here one can find the internal energy to be
$$U=[H]=\textrm{tr}(H\exp(-\beta H))$$
How can one now see that the internal energy is indeed extensive in for example the volume? Wouldn't this require some specific knowledge of the Hamiltonian $H$ involved, from which we can infer how the spectrum of $H$ scales under a change in volume? I'm also interested in understanding how one may generalizes this logic to different work variables, as for example the particle number.

We often use this linear scaling behavior in thermodynamics, but I would like to have a solid understanding of its actual origin.

Comment: this might interest you https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/14845/nonextensive-statistical-mechanics

Answer (score 3):

> How can one now see that the internal energy is indeed extensive in for example the volume?

One cannot. For almost all  interacting systems, finite size effects prevent the internal energy (or other thermodynamic potentials) from being extensive.
The simplest way to see it is to consider the merging into a single system of two equal subsystems in two equal cubic boxes. If a square face is joined to another square face and the confining wall is removed, two surface layers of molecules disappear, with their contribution to the internal energy of the system.

It is only at the thermodynamic limit that one can get rid of the finite size boundary contribution to the energy.

**If** the limit exists, extensiveness is restored for every finite subvolume of the infinite system.
Of course, the form of the Hamiltonian matters in order to be able to prove the existence of the thermodynamic limit.

Comment: Roughly speaking, one would need to require that the Hamiltonian of the composite system is such that there is no interaction between what one would consider as finite subvolumes, right?

Comment: @DvijD.C. yes. But this is almost impossible for systems where particles or other degrees of freedom experience a mutual interaction.